# Broken Google Play on cm 10.1.2

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, updates, 4.2-jelly-bean

I've updated cm from 10.0.0 to 10.1.2, and after updating the gapps too, [several things are broken](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/75232-upgrade-to-1012-messed-up-many-things/), including Gmail and Drive.

Now, **Google Play** lists them at "updatable", but it is broken and **refuses to update any app**, reporting `Error retrieving information from server. [RPC:S-5:AEC-0]`.

Some google services apparently work (Contacts, Calendar), so I guess it's no login problem.

I've tried wiping data of a few related apps, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error *[RPC:S-5:AEC-0]* is down to having to remove your google account and re-add it again.

If your account is primary google account, the only way you can remove it is to factory reset and re-install everything! That is the only known cure and quoted by Google themselves! Do not think they are taking it seriously enough. It broke on a previous update to Google Play Store about two months ago.

I get that too, if keep trying over a few minutes, it will eventually update, not successfully though.

I do think its more of an issue on the Google system itself in conjunction with Play store app.

It's not just confined to AOSP JB/ICS or CyanogenMod, I get in on Gingerbread too.

PS: As matter of curiousity - do you have Google 2-step account verification active on your account?

Comment: Yes I do have 2-step verification active.

Comment: BTW no, even switching account still gives the same error.

Comment: I wiped and re-installed, couldn't be bothered to keep waiting for magic.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have found your answer on your other forum:

- You need to flash the Android 4.2 gapps from http://goo.im/gapps
- reinstall all apps that are having problems

from: http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/75232-upgrade-to-1012-messed-up-many-things/

Comment: Didn't work, sorry.